# Should EndReceive ever return zero if the socket is still connected?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I'm making the following BeginReceive call on a socket:

```
m_socket.BeginReceive(m_buffer, 0, m_buffer.Length, SocketFlags.Partial, this.ReceiveCallback, null);
```

in my classes `ReceiveCallback` function I call

```
try {
    int bytesReadFromSocket = m_socket.EndReceive(ar);
    if(bytesReadFromSocket > 0) {
         // Do some processing
    }
}
finally {
   if(m_socket.Connected) m_socket.BeginReceive(m_buffer, 0, m_buffer.Length, SocketFlags.Partial, this.ReceiveCallback, null);
}
```

The issue I'm having is that EndReceive is returning zero, but m_socket.Connected is returning true, so I call BeginReceive again. This occurs in a tight loop which doesn't ever stop. It's not clear from the documentation when EndReceive returns a zero. I assumed it only happens when the socket is closed, but this does no appear to be true.

So the question remains, under what conditions can EndReceive return zero?

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970825/when-does-endreceive-return-zero-bytes

It seems like besides the 3 circumstances, it would return 0.

Comment: Levi, I already saw that article. It's not really related to the question I'm asking. I'm specifically asking about the return value of EndReceive and if a return value of zero means that there is not going to be any more data available on the socket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Socket.EndReceive()` returns 0 in one specific case: the remote host has begun or acknowledged the graceful closure sequence (e.g. for a .NET `Socket`-based program, calling `Socket.Shutdown()` with either `SocketShutdown.Send` or `SocketShutdown.Both`).

However note that technically, until the socket is finally closed, it is "connected".

You should not use the `Connected` property to determine whether to issue another read from the socket. Instead, since a return value of 0 is specifically reserved to indicate that no more data will be sent, you should simply check the return value of `EndReceive()` and call `BeginReceive()` again if the value is a positive number (i.e. not zero).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that it might have been possible that if the socket wasn't closed properly from the other side, that "Socket.Connected" might not be a valid check to call BeginReceive again. As a matter of fact, it sounds like Connected might sometimes get stuck if the server disconnects, but the client doesn't acknowledge it.

Comment: I guess that depends on your definition of "stuck". If the client fails to acknowledge the shutdown, but still closes its end, or just exits the process without cleaning up, then the server will still see the completion callback invoked, but when you call `EndReceive()`, you'll get an exception (indicating the connection was reset) instead of the 0 return value. One way or the other, the server will eventually learn the socket is no longer connected. :)

Comment: I wasn't getting an exception on EndReceive, I was just getting a return value of zero, and I assumed that zero didn't necessarily mean that there was an error. Would you say that a client should close the socket in the ReceiveCallback if EndReceive returns zero?

Comment: Return value of 0 means the other end called shutdown. _Each_ end should shutdown the socket (_not_ close) when _they_ are done sending data. Each end, once they have already shutdown the socket _and_ have had a receive complete with 0 bytes (either before or after they shutdown their end), _then_ they can close the socket.

Comment: So when EndReceive returns zero, should I call Close, Disconnect or Shutdown in the client? Or a combination of them?

Comment: It depends on what you have left to do. If you had already finished sending data yourself, and so had already called `Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)`, then you close the socket at that point. If you still have data to send, then you just note somewhere (e.g. private flag stored with your connection state...in many cases, one is already maintaining some kind of connection state anyway) that the remote host already shutdown and then when you are done sending, you call `Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)`, and then close the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we are testing the TCP connection, forgot to initialize the buffer array. When it is null or empty, EndReceive() will return 0 always. I have a stupid experience on this.

Comment: This comment just helped me to find the issue, thanks =)